# Sending a Signature Output to Image Field View in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I'm a bit new to Swift and XCode in general, but I'm stuck on the last portion of a playground app I'm working on.

I have a popup with a signature view where a person can sign their name and then proceed to click "done" and the image of their signature to a UIimageView back on the main form. I've got everything working except that while I can technically put the "image" of the signature in its own little frame, I cannot, for the life of me, get the image of the signature to specifically go to a UIimageView box.

Here is my code specifically related to the output of the signature image.

```
    func signature(_ signature: Signature!, didCompleteWith signature: Signature1!) {
            NSLog("-- signature completed. --")

            // display the signature
            outputImage.removeFromSuperview()
            outputImage = signature.imageView
            outputImage.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 452, y:540, width: self.outputImage.frame.size.width, height: self.outputImage.frame.size.height)
            view.addSubview(outputImage)
}
```

I am curious if sending it to a UIimageView is the best option, or if there would be a better was around this to put the image in an input field of sorts.

Comment: Is your `outputImage` (you should name it `outputImageView` to avoid confusion) already sized and positioned where you want the "signature" image to go?

Comment: Why are you passing an `UIImageView` object in a `Signature1`? Just give it an `UIImage`. Then in the function above first prepare your `outputImage` container (apply frame, add to some view), and assign the signature image to it: `outputImage.image = signature.image`

Comment: @VadimPopov, it still pops up with errors, how would you suggest writing it out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `outputImage` is a `UIImageView`, and assuming you already have it in place where you want it (based on the fact your original code is removing it from its superview), you should be able to do it like this:

```
func signature(_ signature: Signature!, didCompleteWith signature: Signature1!) {
        NSLog("-- signature completed. --")

        // display the signature
        outputImage.image = signature.imageView.image
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided doesn't give enough information for debugging. So, either post some more code of `Signature1` class and the `signature` function environment or take a look at **Debug View Hierarchy** button at the Xcode's bottom toolbar.

[image]

It will let you inspect your views positioning and you'll probably notice if there is something wrong with your `outputImage` container.

If the `UIImageView` takes right place, then you have to dig to the direction of the image object taken from signature.